# Не могу установить время в плеере

Tags: javascript

**При клике значение `CurrentTime` сбрасывается до 0**

Делаю обычный бар для перемотки аудио

```
    this.song = new Audio();
    let seekBar = document.querySelector('.seek-bar');

    seekBar.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

            let time = (event.offsetX / seekBar.offsetWidth) * this.song.duration;

            this.song.currentTime = time;

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно выбрать позицию, можно заюзать `input[type="range"]`:

```js
setTimeout(_ => (console.config({maxEntries: 1}), [...document.querySelector('.as-console').childNodes].forEach(e => e.remove())), 10);

let range = document.querySelector('input');

range.min = 1;
range.max = 500; // Length of a media
range.step = 1;

range.addEventListener('input', throttle(function (e) {
  console.info(`Move to ${this.value} sec.`);
}, 100));


function throttle(func, ms) {
  var isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs,
    savedThis;

  function wrapper() {
    if (isThrottled) {
      savedArgs = arguments;
      savedThis = this;
      return;
    }

    func.apply(this, arguments);

    isThrottled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      isThrottled = false;
      if (savedArgs) {
        wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
        savedArgs = savedThis = null;
      }
    }, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type='range' />
```